# How do I work with an array of type (TList, class) with Delphi7

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-7, tlist

I have an old programm with a variable:

```
Modul : array[1..4] of array[0..5] of array[1..3] of TModul;
```

I can store modules in a list:

```
procedure Test;
var
  List: TList;
  PModul: Pointer;
begin
  PModul := Addr(Modul);
  List:= TList.Create;
  List.Add(PModul);
  //... 
  List.Free;
end;
```

but how can I read an element from the list

```
? := Modul[x,y,z].MeasValue.Value[i];
```

from the list?

And how can I pass the modul into function/procedure like this:

```
TTest=class(TObject)
  private
    FModul: TModul;
    function GetModul: TModul;
    procedure SetModul(const Value: TModul); // it isnt't work
  public
    property Modul: TModul read GetModul write SetModul;
 end;
```

so that I can work with my modul and TObjectList?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code probably won't work because `Addr(Modul)` refers to the same instance every time. You probably need to use some dynamic allocation. Or dynamic arrays. If you want to introduce multidimensional indexing to a list, you have to graft that on yourself. Without knowing why you want to change code that apparently works how can we advise you on the best course of action?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to save several measurements to work with them later, for example: delete one, show some in a stringgrid, save. I thought in this case on a list, so my approach. One modul = one  measurement

Comment: Perhaps you want to use a dynamic array, but it's very hard to tell. We don't even know what `TModul` is. I don't think anybody can give you good advice without any real detail.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution:

http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TList_Add.html